# Numpy : find number of active tickets at time t given a list of start and duration

Tags: python, numpy

i have a list of tuples representing the start time of a ticket and its duration

```
tickets = [(start1, duration1), (start2, duration2),...]
```

I would like to know how many tickets are active at a given time t.

The dummy function:

```
def activity(t, tickets):
    tickets.sort()
    gamma = 0
    for point, duration in tickets:
    if point < t and t < point + duration:
        gamma += 1
    return gamma
```

takes too much time and is stupid if you want to calculate activity for a vector of increasing times.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with numpy?

Comment: @kindall if the argument t could be a numpy array it would be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using builtins**

```
def activity(t):
       return  len(filter(lambda x:x[0]<t<x[0]+x[1],tickets))
```

filter is done at a lower level and is optimized more than a for loop so it should be faster...  it doesnt rely  on sort and it just returns a count of whats left

**Using numpy**

```
import numpy as np
tickets = np.array([(start1, duration1), (start2, duration2),...])

def activity(t,tickets):
    t1 = tickets[tickets[:,0]<t] #start times before t
    return t2[t2[:,0]+t2[:,1]>t]   #start+duration after t
```

**using your code** since it is sorted you could always exit the loop once start was greater than t so you dont evaluate all items

```
def activity(t, tickets):
    tickets.sort(key=lambda x:x[0]) #sort by start time
    gamma = 0
    for point, duration in tickets:
        if point < t and t < point + duration:
              gamma += 1
        elif point > t:
              break ; #we can quit looking
    return gamma
```

you could also presort the list and make sure you insert items in the sorted locations (keep the list sorted so you dont have to sort it each time)

[Edit] Updated to correct numpy function

```
>>> x=np.array([(1,2),(2,2),(1,4),(1,1),(3,2)])
>>> x
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 1],
       [3, 2]])
>>> def activity(t,tickets):
...     tmp = tickets[tickets[:,0] < t]
...     return tmp[tmp[:,0]+tmp[:,1] > t]
...
>>> activity(2,x)
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 4]])
>>> activity(3,x)
array([[2, 2],
       [1, 4]])
```

Comment: what is t2 in your numpy version?

Comment: t2 is a list of all entries with the first element less than t... I dont think you can do  2<t<5 type thing inside numpy list index filters...